# How to resolve Failed to read file attributes for "/Users/path/myapp/Images.xcassets" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, assets, xcode9

Suddenly I am getting error in Xcode 9 beta like

"Failed to read file attributes for "/Users/path/myapp/Images.xcassets" in Xcode?" and unable to build as well I just dragged the "Images.Xcassets" folder to up that's it.

I checked targets, Copy Bundle Resources and "Images.Xcassets" folder existed. But, I am unable to build the project.

Comment: did you tried cleaning you project , and deleting `DerivedData`

Comment: Yes, tried all the possible ways.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found out that my folder name is `images.Xcassets`, which Group name and Full Path is `Images.xcassets`. You should check your group name and full path in File inspector.

[image]

EDIT:
Here are two solutions:
1. Remove the group from Project Navigator (ALT+1), and add files back again (OPTION+ALT+A).
2. Click the folder icon from File Inspector (OPTION+ALT+1) and choose a new folder.

Comment: Just a note that renaming it didn't work for me straight away – I had to rename, then remove from project, then add back

Comment: Simply reselecting the same folder updated the path and fixed the case insensitive issue.

Comment: I hadn't installed my git submodules :/

Answer (score 12):

It's an issue of latest Xcode9. There are two ways to solve this issue.

Follow these:

1. Remove reference the images.Xcassets file from your project. Once you remove it from project and add to project again solved my problem.

[image]

2. If option 1 don't work, delete(Trash) the full images.Xcassets file and add all icon again.

Make sure you add this in your icon name Build settings.

Answer (score 7):

"Quit the Xcode and restart." it worked out for me. I got the same problem with Xcode-9.0. I have tried it in multiple ways like deleting Derived data, Cleaning the project and closing the Xcode but nothing worked.

Delete your derived data and then Quit X code
Cmd+q quit the xcode and open it again.

Comment: xCode glitch I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem though, using local pods. It seems that xcodebuild is now case sensitive relative to the resource path.
**~/Folder/MyProject != ~/folder/MyProject**

Comment: It's because now physical project files structure matches Xcode project files structure. xcodebuild is using Xcode project structure and is unable to find a file if physical path of file is different than defined in project.

Answer (score 0):

Closing and reopening Xcode fixed the problem for me